# How to change domain.com to domain.com/folder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this folder structure

```
webroot/
    www/
    srv/
```

When I visit http://www.domain.com, it points to the www/ folder using this codes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /www/$1 [NC,L,NS]
```

It shows the contents of the www/ folder without the folder name on the address bar. It retains its name to:

```
http://www.domain.com
```

What I want is to use the .htaccess mod_rewrite to change from:

```
http://sub.domain.com
```

to

```
http://sub.domain.com/srv
```

Where it shows the sub folder and it contents. Is it possible? I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:sub\.domain\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/srv/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it returns a redirect loop error. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that it isn't already pointing to `/srv`. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:sub\.domain\.com)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/srv/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/srv/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried using this code, but it seems the host is not catching the instruction. When the subdomain is asked by the browser, it displays "Directory Listing Denied". This means that the http://sub.domain.com is not catched by the .htaccess file. You can visit the output here: http://forestfarms.abecomm.com

It still remains as http://forestfarms.abecomm.com/ were it should be http://forestfarms.abecomm.com/srv/